# Strings defined in strings.xml not displayed in "Resource chooser" in graphical layout (main.xml)

Tags: android, eclipse, string

Using this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#first_uiproperties) at section 5.5, I attempted to "Assign the 'celsius' string attribute to the 'text' property of the first radio button and "fahrenheit" to the second"

The "Resource Chooser" (called, by mistake (?), "Reference chooser" in the above article) is displayed but...I can choose only between two strings : "app_name" and "hello". "celsius" and "fahrenheit" attributes are not proposed.

How do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings.xml file has to be SAVED once modified in order to have its modifications taken into account !

Answer (score 0):

In the res/values folder should be an XML file called strings.xml When you open this you will see the values you referred to ("app_name" and "hello"). Make an entry similar to them like this:

```
<string name="celsius">Celsius</string>
```

You could just hard code the text into the text property you are referring to but Android provides this way to store strings of text in an XML file so that they can be 1) easily found in one spot and 2) easily translated if required later. So it is recommended to do it "the Android Way." This is explained in section 5.3 of the tutorial you linked to.

Now you should be able to reference them by the element name (celsius) as you were trying to.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful answer. Actually, I found ths issue... The strings.xml file has to be SAVED once modified in order to have its modifications taken into account ! Sorry for my stupid question, I am (really) new at Android... (first day !) 1.5 year on iOS...not easy to restart from 0 !

Comment: hehe yeah I believe I've done that a least once along the way. Good luck and welcome!